# Loading URLs into an iFrame using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and 
I'm trying to create a Stumbleupon like website but I'm having problems while loading the content into an iFrame. I just cant figure it out how to iterate through each url and load them into the iFrame while clicking in the `<a>` tag.

Here is what I've done:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    urls = [
        'http://www.w3schools.com',
        'http://techcrunch.com/',
        'https://www.fayerwayer.com/',
    ]
    return render_template('index.html', urls=urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**templates/layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/normalize.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/foundation.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <h3 align="center"><a href="?????">Stumble</a></h3>
    </nav>

    {% block content %} 
    {% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

**templates/index.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <iframe frameborder='0' noresize='noresize' style='position: absolute; background: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%;' src="????????" frameborder="0"></iframe>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding `import random` at the top of your app.py file you could structure your code like this:

```
def index():
    urls = [
        'http://www.w3schools.com',
        'http://techcrunch.com/',
        'https://www.fayerwayer.com/',
    ]

    iframe = random.choice(urls)

    return render_template('index.html', iframe=iframe)
```

Then access the value in your template:

```
<iframe frameborder='0' noresize='noresize' style='position: absolute; background: transparent; width: 100%; height:100%;' src="{{ iframe }}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And simply set the Stumble button to refresh the page.

```
<h3 align="center"><a href="/">Stumble</a></h3>
```

This will be pretty basic, but it will have the behaviour you're describing.

An improvement will be to use the [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session) object to make sure that two subsequent requests do not display the same page inside the iframe.

Comment: Thank you very much! this works perfectly! I will actually add the session object, thank you again.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use the session object? I don't understand the documentation and how to use it with the `random.choice`. Please give me some hint.

Comment: You'll have to save the current url to the session, and afterwards you could either pop it from the `urls` list and select from the remaining with `random.choice`, or you could randomly select an url until you pick a different one from what's in your session. Don't forget to replace the url you store in your session, after each pick. Good luck!